# Get unique column combined with LIKE statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got table 'places' with columns: id (unique), name, postal. Names can be duplicated.

I would like to perform query to find first 20 records, where name starts with some `needle`, but without duplicated names. It is for ajax live search. 
The point is that I need to combine this with postal, because I don't want to cut places from different regions. First two letters of postal are enough.

Example of data:

```
id name postal
1 Bradford BD83CB
2 Bradford BD74RT
3 Keighley BD215CT
4 Bradford CC763DD
5 Braster DD339CL
```

The needle here is "Bra%"
The result should contain id of 1 and 4 and 5, because Bradford from record with id 4 is in another region than Bradford from ID 1 and 2.

What I've tried:

```
SELECT id, `name`, postal FROM places WHERE `name` LIKE 'needle%' GROUP BY `name` LIMIT 20
```

But of course it is not enough, because this cut all `names` and I won't have records with id 1, 4, 5, but only with id 1. I should add somewhere condition with postal.

The last thing is that it should be as fast as possible for ajax search.

If there is no option to find this with high performance I consider adding column `searchable` with possible values 0 and 1 and use this in where statement.

Comment: How do i know that postal a and postal b belongs to two different countries? Do you have countries column as well?

Comment: There is nothing to do about country and there is no column with country. Just two first letters of postal determine than if they are the same, place is in the same county/region.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but I cannot test performance.

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T (id INT,name VARCHAR(20), postal VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, 'Bradford' ,'BD83CB'),
(2, 'Bradford' ,'BD74RT'),
(3, 'Keighley' ,'BD215CT'),
(4, 'Bradford' ,'CC763DD'),
(5, 'Braster' ,'DD339CL');


SELECT ID,NAME,POSTAL 
FROM T
WHERE ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM T T1 WHERE T1.NAME = T.NAME AND LEFT(T1.POSTAL,2) = LEFT(T.POSTAL,2))
AND NAME LIKE 'BRA%'
;
```

Result

```
+------+----------+---------+
| ID   | NAME     | POSTAL  |
+------+----------+---------+
|    1 | Bradford | BD83CB  |
|    4 | Bradford | CC763DD |
|    5 | Braster  | DD339CL |
+------+----------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is more simple and have better performance.

```
SELECT id, `name`, postal, substring(postal, 1, 2) FROM places WHERE `name` LIKE 'Bra%' GROUP BY substring(postal, 1, 2);
```

Also this version is running in my setup (maridb 10.1.29)

```
SELECT id, `name`, postal FROM places WHERE `name` LIKE 'Bra%' GROUP BY substring(postal, 1, 2);
```

`+------+----------+---------+
| id   | name     | postal  |
+------+----------+---------+
|    1 | Bradford | BD83CB  |
|    4 | Bradford | CC763DD |
|    5 | Braster  | DD339CL |
+------+----------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)`